# PHP fopen() fails if date() used as directory

Tags: php, date, fopen

My code looks like this:

```
$fp = fopen( getcwd() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . date('d-M-y') . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "example.html", "w" );
```

This code fails for reasons I can't figure out.

This code works just fine though:

```
$fp = fopen( getcwd() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "05-Mar-2013" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "example.html", "w" );
```

At first I assumed that it was an issue with date() not returning a string so I tried casting it to a string, but the function explicitly states that it returns a string so that is not the problem. Has anyone found a resolution to this problem? I need this to be dynamically inserted using the date() function but if that can't work I will have to figure out an alternative directory structure that will still show the date. Thanks

Comment: Try rendering the path to an intermediary variable and checking its contents prior to the call to fopen() -- might offer some insight

Comment: Print the 2 paths and compare them

Comment: you are also missing the 2nd parameter to fopen() which states the 'mode'

Comment: @nathan I have already tried saving the date() result to a variable and then adding it, but this doesn't work either.

Comment: @nathan i forgot to include that in the question, but it is in fact there in my code

Comment: @RudyGarcia I recommend double-checking the entire path, not just the output to date()

Comment: also -- are you certain the code is failing with fopen() and not some later call referencing $fp? .fopen() will return FALSE on error and would help to check does $fp === FALSE?

Comment: another consideration -- what are the file permissions for the containing directory? is the php user able to write to this location?

Comment: Thanks I seemed to have figured it out, apparently the directory was failing because the formatting of the date was off. I used a "y" instead of a "Y". Figures

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `date('d-M-Y')` instead of `date('d-M-y')`.

Comment: Thanks looks like this was the problem. Such minor details make a big difference.